# In jQuery, how do I set opacity only for non-robots

Tags: jquery, opacity, jquery-waypoints

I am using waypoints for bringing some of my content into view as a user scrolls.  Assuming I have a div with class "fadefromcurrent", I apply the following jquery when the page loads:

```
$('.fadefromcurrent').css('opacity',0);
$('.fadefromcurrent.animated').css('opacity',1);
$('.fadefromcurrent').waypoint(function (direction) {
    if (direction == 'down') {
        $(this).addClass('animated fadeIn');
    }
},{
    offset: '90%',
    triggerOnce: true
});
```

The problem I am researching is it seems the content is hidden from search engine robots (at least it appears hidden when I view from Google webmaster tools)

So, I guess this is a two-prong question - does opacity matter to a search engine and, if so, is there a way to only apply this when I know it's a valid browser (non-robot) coming to my site?

Comment: opacity shouldn't matter at all to a search engine like Google, but it might assume it's content that doesn't matter as much, seeing as it's hidden. You can't differentiate between robots and users in clientside javascript, you would have to check the user agent serverside.

Comment: I'd be able to check the user agent on the server and bypass this code.  I'll lookup what to look for on the user agent to differentiate.  Thanks for the tip.